# Execution timeout expired in Entity Framework but works fine in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, entity-framework, executiontimeout

I am calling a SQL Server stored procedure from Entity Framework like this:

```
datacontext.INITIAL_CHECK(FileKey);
```

My connection string has connection time out defined as `600` seconds.

But the stored procedure execution is aborting with an "Execution timeout expired" exception.

When I run the same stored procedure through SQL Server Management Studio, it finishes in 43 seconds.

Comment: The timeout in the connection string is just for this : for **connecting** to the database. It has absolutely **NOTHING** to do with the **command timeout** - how long a command can run before a timeout occurs ....

Comment: @marc_s can you help me hw to set the command timeout in data context with linq?

Comment: Just **search** this site - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=set+command+timeout+in+entity+framework - there are already ***TONS*** of responses.....